# How to implement user validation to only accepting a few letters as valid

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

I'm having trouble with input validation on a program.

```
       public static boolean inputValidation(String input) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
     char c = input.charAt(i);
     if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != A || c != J || c != Q || c != K || c != 'a' || c != 'j' || c != 'q' || c != 'k') {
        return false; 
     }

  }
  return true;
}
```

That is my code so far, but when I run it with the rest of my code it doesn't validate it correctly, it just continues the program as is

```
        int input1 = humanVersion(operands[0]);
        int input2 = humanVersion(operands[1]);
        String input1String = String.valueOf(input1);
        String input2String = String.valueOf(input2);
        boolean valid1 = inputValidation(input1String);
        boolean valid2 = inputValidation(input2String);

   while (!valid1 || !valid2){
      if (!valid1){ 
        System.out.println("invalid input 1");
     }
     if (!valid2){
        System.out.println("invalid input 2");
     }
     System.out.println("Enter valid input: ");

     stringInput = scan.nextLine();
     operands = stringInput.split(" ");
     //
     input1 = humanVersion(operands[0]);
     input2 = humanVersion(operands[1]);
     //
     input1String = String.valueOf(input1);
     input2String = String.valueOf(input2);
     //
     valid1 = inputValidation(input1String);
     valid2 = inputValidation(input2String);

  }
```

The program is based on adding and multiplying 2 numbers that the user inputs that are based on a 14-based number system. with characters 0-9, A, J, K, and Q. 
My idea was to see if there were any letters other than A, J, K, and Q in the input and ask again for the input if there was an invalid one.

Comment: I have more code in the same program if needed. I think this should be enough to help though

Comment: You need `&&` instead of `||`.  All over the place.  Every character is either not equal to `a` or not equal to `b`.  Also, don't forget to put _all_ your character literals inside single quote marks, like `'a', 'b'` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your *inputValidation()* method

1. There is compilation error; instead of `c != A` you should enclose `A` in single inverted commas because you're referring to a character here, not a variable
2. The *if* logic doesn't seems to be right. If you want to find that your character is within a certain set or characters or not, you should use `||`.

You can modify the if statement like this and then it should work

```
if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == 'A' || c == 'J' || c == 'Q' 
      || c == 'K' || c == 'a' || c == 'j' || c == 'q' || c == 'k')) {
...
```

Or by using your logic, put `&&` all over the place:

```
if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != 'A' && c != 'J' && c != 'Q'
      && c != 'K' && c != 'a' && c != 'j' && c != 'q' && c != 'k') {
```